# A variant of Dijkstra's to choose optimal source between all nodes

Tags: graph-theory

I have a question about graph theory, which I am not very well versed in.

Currently:
I am using Dijkstra's algorithm to find the optimal path from a single source to all other nodes.
My network is non-directional and each edge has a value between [0, 1].
The value given to each node is the value of the worst edge (lowest value) on the best path (highest value).

I have added a simple Image here:
[Simple Dijkstra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQFwP.png)
Where the source is blue, the edge values are black, the node values are red, and the edges used by the algorithm are also red.

My problem:
If I choose a bad node (one with only low value edges connected to it), all the other nodes will be defined by those first edges, and they will have very low values.

I got the idea of trying to optimize my results by choosing the best source, the source that optimizes eg. the average or median value of all nodes.

I tried to brute force it in a for loop where I looped over all the nodes as sources, which is gonna take a while, I have 50000 nodes, and 200000 edges.
Which, with my own implementation of Dijkstra, is gonna take several days

I have looked on the internet for similar algorithms but have not found any that seemed suitable.

My question is, does such an algorithm exist, or do I just have to brute force it?

Best Regards,
Jakob

Comment: Could you precise what the edges values and node values correspond to?

Comment: The node values are given from the edge values.
The edge values are a measure of the quality of that specific edge, such that 1 is a perfect edge quality, and 0 is the worst value.

Comment: Ah, so you are trying to find a node $s$ such that for each other node $v$, you evaluate the quality of an $sv$ path is the quality of edge of lowest value. Then the node value is the value of the best $sv$ path. It seems quite different from the djikstra's algorithm. You mentionned using average and median node value, I guess you can also consider a robust objective function (would be maximizing the worst node value).

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing, I realize it is a modification of Dijkstra, but they were using Dijkstra in a related paper, so I figured it was best to do that as well.
But what I wanted to do now, which it does not seem like Dijkstra can do, is to find the source node which optimizes the values of all other node, eg. the source node which makes all other nodes have the highest average or median value.
Currently I have tried to find the optimal source by brute force, but it takes too long to be feasible, do you have any suggestion for an algorithm that could do something like that?

Comment: Is there a practical application behind this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have a look at [Prim's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) algorithm. Basically, it grows a tree step by step by starting from no edge selected to a subtree of your graph, and at each step it select the edge with higher value to put in the tree. This is how it goes:

1. Sort the edge set $E$ in decreasing order. (will be very useful in step 3)
2. For each node $s$: let $S = \{s\}$ be the set of reached nodes
3. While $S \ne V$, pick the edge $ab$ of highest value such that  $a\in S$ and $b \in V-S$. Then you grow the reached nodes $S = S + \{b\}$.
4. compute the metric you are interested in, and go back to step 2.

The step 3 can be donne quite efficiently using appropriate data structures. (fibonnacci heaps etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think this would be a better choice of algorithm than Dijkstra.

But I cannot see how it solves the problem of choosing the optimal source?

Comment: For each node you build this tree. When the tree is complete you can compute the value of every other node according to the path from the source. You repeat this for every node, so you consider that potentially every node can be a source. In some sense it's probably a very similar approach to what you actually did with djikstra algorithm, but djikstra is for distances which is not exactly what you look for in the description of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add a dummy sink  node $t$ linked to all vertices.

Define binary variable $x_{ij}$ that takes value $1$ if and only if edge $(i,j)$ is used, binary variable $y_j$ that takes value $1$ if and only if node $j$ is selected to be the source.

You need to enforce the following constraints:

- Exactly one source:
  $$
  \sum_{j\neq t} y_j=1
  $$
- Flow conservation constraints:
  $$
  \sum_i x_{ji}-\sum_i x_{ij}=(n-1)y_j \quad \forall j\neq t
  $$
- One unit of flow exactly from each non source node to the sink:
  $$
  x_{jt}+y_j=1 \quad \forall j\neq t
  $$

Then optimize your metric (maximize the worst node value) subject to the above constraints.